# Automating a routine in R

Tags: r, optimization

Given my data (**see below**), I'm using ***several*** **"length" + "which" statements (see below)** to explore my data.

**Q1.** Is there an efficient code to **automatize** this instead of using these many lines of code?

**Q2.** Can I summarize the answers from all **"length" + "which" statements** in a table? (For example, for the **first** **"length" + "which" statement** where the answer is **9,** a table can say **"1st quadrant"** and next to or below it **9**)?

Here is **my data** and the **"length" + "which" statements** that I have created:

```
x <- c(2,1,5,4,5,8,6,6,4,1,2,2,2,5,9,5,4,3,2,3,1,3,1,7,3,2,2,9,7,7,9,8,8,6,4,6,7,2,1,4,3,9)
y <- c(1,2,2,8,7,4,6,7,5,5,2,9,3,9,1,5,7,1,8,6,8,4,9,2,7,5,7,6,3,8,3,3,7,8,3,4,4,4,3,6,5,4)

## HERE is my "length" + "which" statements:

length(x[which(x < 5 & y <5)]) ## 1st quadrant datapoints (Left Bottom)
length(x[which(x < 5 & y >5)]) ## 2rd quadrant   "
length(x[which(x > 5 & y >5)]) ## 3rd quadrant   "
length(x[which(x > 5 & y <5)]) ## 4rd quadrant datapoints (Right Bottom)

length(x[which(x < 5)]) ## 1st left half
length(x[which(x > 5)]) ## 2nd right half
length(x[which(y < 5)]) ## 1st Bottom half
length(x[which(y > 5)]) ## 2nd Top half

length(x[which(x==5)]) ## Balanced Scope
length(x[which(y==5)]) ## Balanced Technicality
length(x[which(x==5 & y==5)]) ## Equal Scope and Technicality

length(x[which(y==5)]) ## How many of Xs have a Y of 5
length(y[which(x==5)]) ## How many of Ys have a X of 5
```

Comment: check out `?cut` and `?table` ...

Comment: You don't need any of the `which()` statements here. As [stated by H. Wickham:](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) "When first learning subsetting, a common mistake is to use `x[which(y)]` instead of `x[y]`."

Comment: @RHertel that depends how you want to deal with NA values. If using `x[y]` and `y` contains an NA value, you will insert an NA value at that position. If you want to avoid that, you use either `isTRUE` or `which`. I also use `which` to store a small subset and save quite some memory compared to a full length logical vector defining the same subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just create a nice table with your own description, then the best way is to do it simply with "many" lines.

```
names=c("1st quadrant", "2rd quadrant", "3rd quadrant", "...")
numbers=c(length(x[x < 5 & y <5]), length(x[x < 5 & y >5]), length(x[x > 5 & y >5]), 12345)

new_table=data.frame(names,numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd like to note that `length(x[which(logical_vector)])` is just `sum(logical_vector)` if this vector's length is no more than the length of `x` (in your case they are always of the same length).

But I'm going to suggest a different approach rather than summing up logical vectors. x and y represent coordinates of points in a plane, so it would be natural to have them bound into one dataframe, as following:

```
d <- data.frame(x, y)
```

The only thing that really matters about x's and y's is what are the signs of `(x - 5)` and `(y - 5)` expressions (I'll illustrate it further). Let's calculate them.

```
library(dplyr)
d <- mutate(d, sx = sign(x - 5), sy = sign(y - 5))
head(d)

  x y sx sy
1 2 1 -1 -1
2 1 2 -1 -1
3 5 2  0 -1
4 4 8 -1  1
5 5 7  0  1
6 8 4  1 -1
```

So, to explain: if a point e.g. has `sx = -1` and `sy = -1` it means that for this point `x < 5` and `y < 5` so we can determine the quadrant only knowing `sx` and `sy`.

Now we need to create sort of a dictionary which would tell us what the quadrant is by `sx` and `sy`. It is quite simple:

```
library(tibble)
quadrant <- tribble(
    ~sx, ~sy, ~quadrant,
     -1,  -1,         1,
     -1,   1,         2,
      1,   1,         3,
      1,  -1,         4
)
```

Then we can simply merge `d` with it to get the `quadrant` variable (some points will have NAs, but that's not a problem):

```
d <- merge(d, quadrant, all.x = T)
```

And, finally, to get the summary by quadrants we do

```
count(d, quadrant)

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  quadrant     n
     <dbl> <int>
1        1     9
2        2    10
3        3     6
4        4     9
5       NA     8
```